# IntelliJ IDEA - Enter cannot open file in Search Everywhere

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I usually find a file by press `Shift Shift`, search by name then `Enter` to open file.

A few couple of days back, when I find files it shows a list of files as usual but it opens nothing when I hit `Enter` which is really strange. `Ctrl Shift N` still works perfectly, however. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200654) in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5 on Linux.

Your options now are as follows:

1. Use [2018.3 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/)
2. Revert to [2018.2.4](https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-2018.2.4.tar.gz)
3. Wait for 2018.2.6 bugfix update
4. Enable `new.search.everywhere` in `Help` | `Find Action`, [Experimental Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpbAA.png) dialog.

Comment: FYI, seeing this with CLion 2018.2.5 on Ubuntu, too.